# ArcGIS Server Search Service and mapped client drives

Tags: arcgis-server, web-service

With ArcGIS Server (10.1), is it possible to register a folder to the [Search Service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Search_services/015400000383000000/) for indexing using one path, and serve it to users with another? how?

For example the server sees `\\geodata-server\data` and `\\geodata-server\maps` while the clients use `Z:\` and `Y:\` respectively.

Under *.../arcgiserver:6080/arcgis/manager/site.html >> Date Store* I've registered and validated the folders, and successfully published map services with these settings, but the data store settings appear to be ignored by Search Service: search results in the clients show the UNC path.

```
Data Store:
   Name: Repository
   Publisher Folder Path: Z:\
   Publisher Folder Hostname: geodata-server
   Server Folder Path: \\geodata-server\data
```

I already tried just using the same mapped drive settings on the arcgis server, but that doesn't work (c.f. [Is it possible to reference data using mapped network drives instead of UNC path in arcgis server services?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/is-it-possible-to-reference-data-using-mapped-network-drives-instead-of-unc-path))